# Why the "401 Unauthorized" when using Call HTTP Web Service against a text file?

Tags: workflow, rest, file

I have a `mydata.txt` file under `SiteAssets` whose contents are JSON (SharePoint prevented my use of a `.json` extension).  I shared the file with Everyone.  I can make a getJSON request with jQuery in the browser to access and read the file's contents.  When I attempt to read the file's contents on the back end in SharePoint workflows using Call HTTP Web Service I get a 401.

I was careful to get context info as per:
http://blog.appliedis.com/2014/10/09/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-working-with-web-services/

I should make the distinction that if I point the Call HTTP Web Service to some list I successfully get the contents of that list.  It's only when I point the URL at a flat file that I get the Unauthorized exception so this seems to indicate some particulars with files access.

It made no difference whether I tried to read an `.xml` or `.html` file or relocate the file to a `Documents` library.  Access was denied.  I can't see as to why a flat file (one that gets periodically updated) couldn't be used as a valid source of information via a REST endpoint.

What am I missing?  Why is this at all complicated?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pointing at `/SiteAssets/mydata.txt` I pointed at `/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/SiteAssets')/Files('mydata.txt')/$value` and used these headers:

```
 Accept: application/octet-stream
 Content-Type: application/octet-stream
 X-RequestDigest: <obtained in an earlier request>
```

I was then able to process the response (which I left as JSON) as a dictionary.

This resource helped:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553.aspx